# Why ONLY internet explorer will not load my Google Maps object

Tags: html, google-maps, internet-explorer-9

Can someone please help me figure out why IE9 won't load my google map but the rest of the main browsers will.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the actual setup or headers instead of the javascript, but let me know if you want that as well.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps API Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api       /js?sensor=false"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />  
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>

   <input type="text" id="search" >
   <input type="button" onclick="search();" value="Search">
<input type="button" onclick="addlaunchMark();" value="Add Launch">
<input type="checkbox" id="launches" checked="checked" onchange="addRemovelaunch()">
</br>
<input type="textbox" id="box1" style="display: none">
<input type="textbox" id="box2" style="display: none">

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: hmm btw.. are you missing doctype declaration above <html> ? <!DOCTYPE html> also end tag </html> are missing.. because of mistake in your paste or something else?

Comment: for some reason I didn't think you could declare that after PHP code.  I did it and it works so THANK YOU!

Comment: Great, I post it as an answer so you can accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem were caused because of missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration, (damn you IE) :)

> It is important to add because it tells browsers which kind of html is
>   used in the document. Document which lacks DOCTYPE will be rendered in
>   bugwards compatibility mode, since it is assumed to be an older
>   document which was written before DOCTYPE became widely used.

[Source](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/synd/2001/08/28/doctype.html)

Comment: You should guide the OP why that makes a difference.

Comment: Hey Hakre, you wanna stop down grading all my questions.  Some of us are new to programming and don't know everything.  That is why forums are create.